# django apache integration missing module

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, python-venv

I'm trying to setup my first Django project and I have some issues with the Apache integration.

Here my file tree

```
venv-django
aci_project/
    |_manage.py
    |_aci_project/
    |   |_ __init__.py
    |   |_settings.py
    |   |_ urls.py
    |   |_ asgi.py
    |   |_ wsgi.py
    |
    |_aci_api/
        |_ __init__.py
        |_aci_script
        |_admin.py
        |_apps.py
        |_migrations/
        |   |_ __init__.py
        |_static --> css
        |_templates --> template html
        |_tests.py
        |_urls.py
        |_views.py
```

Basically, the flow is the following:

Browser --> aci_project --> urls.py --> aci_api --> views.py --> call scripts in aci_script

If I run the command "python manage.py runserver" it's working fine.

Now I'm trying to integrate my Django project with Apache but it's not working.

This is my vhost file in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combine

    <Directory /var/opt/aci_project/aci_project/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIApplicationGroup aciweb01t.stluc.ucl.ac.be
WSGIDaemonProcess aciweb01t.stluc.ucl.ac.be group=www-data python-path=/var/opt/aci_project
WSGIProcessGroup aciweb01t.stluc.ucl.ac.be
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/opt/aci_project/aci_project/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

here my wsgi.py file in aci_project --> manage.py --> _aci_project

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'aci_project.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And this is the error I have in the apache logs:

```
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.468252 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031] mod_wsgi (pid=7818): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/opt/aci_project/aci_project/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.468453 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031] mod_wsgi (pid=7818): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/opt/aci_project/aci_project/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.468926 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469073 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "/var/opt/aci_project/aci_project/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469092 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469109 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "/var/opt/venv-django/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469118 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469132 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "/var/opt/venv-django/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469140 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469153 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "/var/opt/venv-django/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469162 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]     self._setup(name)
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469175 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "/var/opt/venv-django/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469183 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469196 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "/var/opt/venv-django/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469204 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469234 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469245 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469259 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469272 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469285 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469298 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469323 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469337 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469350 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Wed Apr 22 16:49:12.469412 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140205314995968] [remote 10.195.113.74:28031] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aci_project'
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I add to update the file wsgi.py as follow:

```
#sys.path.append('/var/opt/aci_project')
sys.path.append('/var/opt/aci_project/aci_project')
sys.path.append('/var/opt/aci_project/aci_api')

#os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'aci_project.settings')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')
```